# How to disable show all in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database table with about 200 rows, so I enable "show all" to show all rows, now the table is about 5 million rows and I can't access browse the data anyone as it's trying to show all rows and I'm getting an error:

```
Error in processing request
Error code: 500
Error text: Internal Server Error (rejected)
It seems that the connection to the server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.
```

How can I disable show all when I can't access browse.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your configuration (config.inc.php) file on your phpmyadmin directory, it was on

```
https://www.blablabla.bla/pathtoyourPHPMyAdminDir/
```

There was config that allow you to disable and limit total rows of it.
Which written

```
$cfg['ShowAll']
```

For the detail of documentation of it was found in this [page](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html)